# How do I install an external library in Codalab

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a competition at https://competitions.codalab.org/. The following metadata file works:

```
command: python3 $program/evaluate.py $input $output
```

But I cannot make it install an external library. How do I do it?
The following variants do not work:

```
command: pip3 install some_external_module
command: python3 $program/evaluate.py $input $output
```

```
command: pip3 install some_external_module && python3 $program/evaluate.py $input $output
```

```
command: pip3 install some_external_module
python3 $program/evaluate.py $input $output
```

Comment: What is an external library? A python library on PyPi? Or Linux package? Have you tried `python3 -m pip install <library>` ?

Comment: it's a python library on PyPi, this method does not unfortunately work but I've managed to do it in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it by inserting the installation process into the `evaluate.py` script itself:

```
def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

install(<my-package>)
import <my-package>
```